# List Re-Order is mixing up property values across list items

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a strange situation happening or maybe it is my misunderstanding of lists, or it is one of those cases where you look at it too long and am missing something simple.

When I re-order a list in this example, it is mixing up column values across rows in the list. Here are some pics as an example as captured during debugging.

In the below pic, first note the list ordering done on 783. Next note the ItemId value of position [0] in the list. It is 1121.
[image: Image 1]

Now after just advancing from line 793 to 798, note the values of `inventoryNeed` after it has been assigned the value from `lstInventoryNeeds[i]`. Note that its ItemId value is 1336! And further, the same list entry in position [0] also changed JUST the ItemId value from 1121 to 1336! What just happened?!?! 
[image: Image 2]

Now if I comment out the original list re-order code on line 783 and run it again, see this pic, captured just after the inventoryNeed assignment when i = 0 just as before, but there is no mix up in the ItemId value.
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Here is code for this section, but not sure how useful it is taken out of context:

```
private ActionConfirmation<int> AllocateContainersForNeedList(List<AllocationNeedViewModel> lstInventoryNeedsOriginal, int intUserId, bool failOnShortage)
{
    //Sort by this so if first alloc attempt fails for the remnant, 
    //then add that qty to next Need in list (if exists) and attempt allocate for full sheets
    var lstInventoryNeeds = lstInventoryNeedsOriginal;
        //.OrderBy(x => x.ItemId)
        //.ThenByDescending(x => x.IsRemnant)
        //.ToList();

    ActionConfirmation<int> allocateResult = ActionConfirmation<int>.CreateSuccessConfirmation("Allocation of Containers for Needs List Successful.",1);
    bool firstOfTwoNeedsForSameItem = false;

    AllocationNeedViewModel inventoryNeed;

    for (int i = 0; i < lstInventoryNeeds.Count; i++)
    {
        inventoryNeed = lstInventoryNeeds[i];

        //If this is an inventory tracked item, allocate it
        if (boolIsInvenTrackedItem(inventoryNeed.ItemId))
        {
            //Allocate the required inventory for the need just created
            if (lstInventoryNeeds.Count() > i + 1)
            {
                firstOfTwoNeedsForSameItem = inventoryNeed.IsRemnant && (lstInventoryNeeds[i + 1].ItemId == inventoryNeed.ItemId);
            }
            else
            {
                firstOfTwoNeedsForSameItem = false;
            }

            allocateResult =
                AllocInvenForNeed(
                    inventoryNeed.FacilityId,
                    inventoryNeed,
                    intUserId,
                    0,
                    0,
                    !firstOfTwoNeedsForSameItem
                );

            //Create Allocation Error
            if (!allocateResult.WasSuccessful)
            {
                //Check if original attempt was for a Remnant
                if (firstOfTwoNeedsForSameItem)
                {
                    //Add current remnant need to the next need for this item, which will then get allocated on the next loop
                    lstInventoryNeeds[i + 1].QtyNeeded = lstInventoryNeeds[i + 1].QtyNeeded + inventoryNeed.QtyNeeded;
                }
                else
                {
                    return allocateResult;
                }
            }
        } //if inventory tracked item

    }//for loop

    return allocateResult;
}
```

Here is a MCVE, but I can't replicate the problem...but maybe I'm missing some key element that would have an impact

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lstInventoryNeedsOriginal = new List<AllocNeedVM>();

            int b = 5;
            for (int a = 0; a <= b; a++)
            {
                int c = b - a;
                var allocNeed = new AllocNeedVM()
                {                    
                    ItemId = c,
                    ItemDesc = "Item " + c.ToString(),
                    IsRemnant = false
                };

                lstInventoryNeedsOriginal.Add(allocNeed);
            }

            AllocNeedVM inventoryNeed;
            Console.WriteLine("List before sort.");
            for (int i = 0; i < lstInventoryNeedsOriginal.Count; i++)
            {
                inventoryNeed = lstInventoryNeedsOriginal[i];
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", inventoryNeed.ItemId, inventoryNeed.ItemDesc, inventoryNeed.IsRemnant);
            }

            var lstInventoryNeeds = lstInventoryNeedsOriginal
                .OrderBy(x => x.ItemId)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.IsRemnant)
                .ToList();


            Console.WriteLine("List after sort.");
            for (int i = 0; i < lstInventoryNeeds.Count; i++)
            {
                inventoryNeed = lstInventoryNeeds[i];
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", inventoryNeed.ItemId, inventoryNeed.ItemDesc, inventoryNeed.IsRemnant);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class AllocNeedVM
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
        public bool IsRemnant { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could copy/paste and run?

Comment: please put in your question code, not pictures of code.

Comment: or maybe in addition too

Comment: Wierd, probably VS crazy thing.. Did you tried reopening VS ?

Comment: @OrelEraki It's not just the way VS is showing it in the debugger, as the results of the executed code are resembling this scenario as well.

Comment: Are you using a database like SQL for source of data?  SQL Server does not return data in the same order every time so you need to use an Order By in the SQL to always get same order.  When you comment out the Order By all bets are off for the ordering of the data.  You are not comparing Apples with Apples is the simple answer without the Order By.

Comment: @jdweng yes, I am using SQL Server, but it is not the order of the list that is the problem, the problem is that it is mixing column values across rows...i.e. row 1 column 1 is showing the value from row 2...so if you had 2 columns and row 1 was a,a and row 2 was b,b, after the sort, the result is a, b and b,a....mixing row values.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I added the MVCE, but it wouldn't replicate my problem...maybe I made it to "M" :)

Comment: Item zero is going to be a different value depending if you have the order by.  SQL Server is multi-threaded query where the threads are run in parallel.  So every time you perform a query you get a different order.